# Carrierwave - Upload from remote image url with no file extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

When trying to upload an image using remote_image_url with Rails and Carrierwave, an error response is returned if the url doesn't have a file extension.

"Failed to manipulate with rmagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: no encode delegate for this image format"

For example, "http://1.gravatar.com/blavatar/999116b97a3284a6b130eda28e875f47?s=300" fails.
Where as "http://1.gravatar.com/blavatar/999116b97a3284a6b130eda28e875f47.png" works.

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a white list in your uploader? In $classname_uploader.rb, whis would be

```
def extension_white_list
 %w($some_file_extenstions)
end
```

and that could cause the problem you describe.